# Ошибка в gulp 4 с task()

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу скомпелировать scss код в css все плагины подключены папка с файлами создана

Comment: Код вашей сборки покажете?)

Comment: Из скриншота следует, что Ваш код в gulpfile.js пытается выполнить очевидно некорректную команду `mkdir '<тут путь>\*.css'`. Соответственно, Вам надо лишь исправить этот код.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все исправил